# Python2のOpenCV3でエラー

Tags: python, opencv, python2

画像をグレイスケールに変換しようといましたがcvが見当たらないというエラーがでてしまいました。

**エラー**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_recognition.py", line 13, in <module>
    image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cv'
```

**コード**

```
#conding:utf-8

import cv2

cascade_path = "/usr/local/opt/opencv3/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"

image_path = "lena.png"

color = (255, 255, 255)

image = cv2.imread(image_path)

image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)

cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade_path)

facerect = cascade.detectMultiScale(image_gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighborsi=3, minSize=(1,1))

print "face rectangle"
print facerect

if len(facerect) > 0:
    for rect in facerect:
        cv2.rectangle(image, tuple(rect[0:2]), tuple(rect[0:2]+rect[2:4]), color, thickness=2)

    cv2.imwrite("detected.jpg", image)
```

おそらく`/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.0.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`下のcv.pyをvirtualenv環境のsite-packageにシンボリックリンクを貼ればいいと思いますが、そのcv.pyがありませんでした(cv2.soはあったのでリンクをはりました)。
どのようにすればいいのでしょうか。

環境
Mac OSX Elcaptan
virtualenv使用(Python 2.7)
opencv3をHomebrewでインストール済み

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV3では名前空間が整理されて`cv2.cv.CV_BGR2GRAY`は`cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY`になりました。他のcv2.cv.CV_...もこんな感じで移行されています。それで見つからない場合はマニュアルを検索してください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。おかげ様でできました!