# Python & OpenCV でグレイスケール化をしたいのですが、AttributeError が出てしまう

Tags: python, python3, opencv

使用ツール
・Python 3.6
・OpenCV 4.5 (※最新版を入れました)
・Anaconda 3.0

初めて画像処理に触れました。最初は本当に楽しく出来そうだなぁと感じていたのですが、エラーが出てしまって、全くプログラムが動きません。

OpenCVのバージョンが異なる為、動かないと言われたのですが、正直に言いますと、どこが違っているのか分かりません。

出てきたエラー

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'cvtcolor'
```

動かしたいコード

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread(r"C:\library_cv\sky_006.jpg)
gray = cv2.cvtcolor(image, cv2.COLOR.BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite(r"C:\write_cv\gray_006.jpg")
```

上記のコードに `cv2.countNonZero` を使って、白の割合を出すのが目標です。
※画像名は仮想ですが、概ねこの通りです。

Comment: もしかしたら単に`cvtcolor`と`cvtColor`の大文字小文字の違いかもしれませんね。[Python, OpenCV, NumPyでカラー画像を白黒（グレースケール）に変換](https://note.nkmk.me/python-opencv-numpy-color-to-gray/)

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'COLOR'`とエラーが出てしまいます...

Comment: 他にも幾つかtypoがあるので、それを直せば動作します。回答しておきましょう。

Comment: 「OpenCVのバージョンが異なる為、動かない」は誰の発言でしょうか？ / "OpenCV は最新版" とのことですが、この手のツールはメジャーバージョンが変わると挙動が変わる可能性があります。何かを参考にしているならそちらにバージョンを合わせるか、自分の使いたいバージョンのドキュメントを確認する必要があると思います。 / 過去の関連質問: [Python2のOpenCV3でエラー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/21773)

Comment: yahoo!知恵袋にも同様の質問をさせていただいたのですが…そう言われました。参考にしているモノは大体openCV3.0系でしたけど、4.0とはあまり変わらないと聞いています。

Answer (score 3):

質問のエラーも含めて幾つか typo があります。
以下のようにすれば動作するでしょう。

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread(r"C:\library_cv\sky_006.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite(r"C:\write_cv\gray_006.jpg", gray)
```

- `imread`のファイル名の`"`が閉じていない(質問時の転記ミスでしょう)
- `cvtcolor`の`color`は大文字で始まる`cvtColor`
- `cv2.COLOR.BGR2GRAY`は`cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY`の間違い(`.`ではなく`_`で接続する)
- `imwrite`は2つ目のパラメータにイメージのオブジェクトを指定する必要がある

---

コメントのリンク先は正しくはこちら
[Python,OpenCVで二値画像から白と黒の面積比を算出](https://techtech-sorae.com/pythonopencv%E3%81%A7%E4%BA%8C%E5%80%A4%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E7%99%BD%E3%81%A8%E9%BB%92%E3%81%AE%E9%9D%A2%E7%A9%8D%E6%AF%94%E3%82%92%E7%AE%97%E5%87%BA/)

上記記事の`bw_image`は2値化された画像データのオブジェクトです。
仕様はこちら。
[cv::threshold](http://opencv.jp/opencv-2svn/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#cv-threshold)
[画像の閾値処理](http://whitewell.sakura.ne.jp/OpenCV/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html)
[Python: cv2.threshold(src, thresh, maxval, type[, dst]) → retval, dst](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cv2.threshold#cv2.threshold)

使い方などの記事はこちら。
[OpenCV – 画像処理の2値化の仕組みと cv2.threshold() の使い方](https://pystyle.info/opencv-image-binarization/)
[cv2.threshold()](https://pystyle.info/opencv-image-binarization/#outline__4)

> - 返り値
>
>   - retval: 閾値 (cv2.THRESH_OTSU、cv2.THRESH_TRIANGLE を使用した場合に自動的に決まった閾値を知るための返り値)
>   - dst: 2値画像

Comment: 無事に動きました！ありがとうございます！もう一つだけお聞きしたいのですが下記リンクサイトの`bw_image`というのは関数名なのでしょうか？[https://techtech-sorae.com/pythonopencv%E3%81%A7%E4%BA%8C%E5%80%A4%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E7%99%BD%E3%81%A8%E9%BB%92%E3%81%AE%E9%9D%A2%E7%A9%8D%E6%AF%94%E3%82%92%E7%AE%97%E5%87%BA/]

Comment: ありがとうございます！！２値化という事はわかっていましたが、ようやく理解したみたいです。また何かありましたら質問させてください…